# Some components are stuck in starting if there is any Kafka input in Talend

Tags: apache-kafka, talend

[image]

Hi everyone,
I got some issues with Kafka input in talend, if there is any Kafka input component in the Talend job, some components are stuck in Starting as you saw in the picture after tExtractJSONFields_1 component, it happens to some components like tuniqrow, taggregate. I already test the job and change the input components with file delimiter input, but it not showing any problem.

is there any special configuration for the Kafka input component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

because Kafka still waiting for messages and it's not waiting and delivering messages at the same time, we can set configurations in Kafka input basic settings, there is 3 way to deliver Kafka messages,

1. send messages after waiting for a specific duration
2. send messages after a number of messages
3. send messages after waiting time between messages